# Check Input contain Text and Number using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a input text field in my webpage. I need to validate this field like the field contain both text and numbers. ie my input box if for cost so I need to validate if the cost is in the format of '100 R'

I have validated the number, but how can I validate text and number

```
var number = document.forms["myForm"]["cost"].value;

if (isNaN(number)) {
    alert("cost must be in number");

    document.myForm.cost.focus() 
    return false;
}
```

Comment: best way to use regex

Comment: `/\d\d\dR/.test(number)`

Comment: if (/\d\d\dR/.test(number))  this not working

Comment: if (!(/\d\d\dR/.test(number)))  ok this working